# Set background to gradient animation drawable not work

Tags: background, gradient, drawable, animationdrawable

This is my first post. Please dont shoot me. LOL

I successfully write code for gradient AnimationDrawable in one of activity. But when I try to implement the code in Theme Activity, it say :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMrVz.png)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.learn.notetoself, PID: 1194
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable
        at com.learn.notetoself.ThemeActivity.onClick(ThemeActivity.java:936)
```

Gradle Scripts (module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.learn.notetoself"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.3.0'
    def nav_version = "2.5.3"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
    implementation 'com.github.xabaras:RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator:1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'

}
```

**SUCCESSFUL ACTIVITY (ARCHIED ACTIVITY)**

XML with Relative Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ArchivedActivity">

<View
    android:id="@+id/background_image_archive"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_list" />
```

JAVA in onCreate medhod (my code applied drawer navigation)

```
public class ArchivedActivity extends DrawerBaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityArchivedBinding = ActivityArchivedBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

//      Load themes
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int selectedTheme = mPrefs.getInt("SelectedThemeNav", 0);
        setDynamicTheme(selectedTheme);

        setContentView(activityArchivedBinding.getRoot());

        // Set animation of changing color for app background
        // Initialize the constraintLayout reference with the ConstraintLayout instance in the Archivedlayout
        View imageViewArchive = findViewById(R.id.background_image_archive);
        AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) imageViewArchive.getBackground();
        // Set parameter to our animation
        // 2500 = 2.5 seconds, 5000 = 5 seconds
        animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(2000);
        animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(5000);
        animationDrawable.start();
}
```

**ERROR ACTIVITY (THEME ACTIVITY)**

XML with Constraint Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ThemeActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/holderbg"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnColorfulNav"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_green"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnBlueBg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnBlueBg" />
```

JAVA in onCreate medhod (I do not paste all contents) (my code applied drawer navigation)

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
ImageButton btnColorfulNav,
View holderbg;

public class ThemeActivity extends DrawerBaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityThemeBinding = ActivityThemeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

//      Load themes for navigation bar
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
//        mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MODE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int selectedThemeNav = mPrefs.getInt("SelectedThemeNav", 0);
        setDynamicThemeNav(selectedThemeNav);

        setContentView(activityThemeBinding.getRoot());


//      Load themes for previous selected background
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int selectedThemeBg = mPrefs.getInt("SelectedThemeBg", 0);
//        setDynamicThemeBg(selectedThemeBg);
        setThemeButtonConfirm(selectedThemeNav);

        btnColorfulNav = findViewById(R.id.btnColorfulNav);
        holderbg = findViewById(R.id.holderbg);


        btnColorfulNav.setOnClickListener(this);


    private void setThemeButtonConfirm(int selectedThemeBg) {
        switch (selectedThemeBg){
            case 10:
//              Set the scale of previous button clicked
                btnColorfulNav.setScaleX(1.2f);
                btnColorfulNav.setScaleY(1.2f);

                btnThemeSave.setBackgroundResource(R.color.theme9ColorPrimary);
//                holderbg.setBackgroundResource(R.color.theme9ColorOnSecondary);
                AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) holderbg.getBackground();
                // Set parameter to our animation
                // 2500 = 2.5 seconds, 5000 = 5 seconds
                animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(2000);
                animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(5000);
                animationDrawable.start();
                break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mEditor = mPrefs.edit();

        switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.btnColorfulNav:
        //                Set scale animation
                        btnColorfulNav.animate().translationY(0).scaleX(1.2f).scaleY(1.2f).setDuration(800).start();
        
        //                Default the scale buttons
                        btnRedNav.animate().translationY(0).scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(350).start();
                        btnOrangeNav.animate().translationY(0).scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(350).start();
                        btnYellowNav.animate().translationY(0).scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(350).start();
                        btnGreenNav.animate().translationY(0).scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(350).start();
                        btnBlueNav.animate().translationY(0).scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(350).start();
                        btnIndigoNav.animate().translationY(0).scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(350).start();
                        btnVioletNav.animate().translationY(0).scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(350).start();
                        btnPinkNav.animate().translationY(0).scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(350).start();
        
                        // Set animation of changing color for app background
                        // Initialize the constraintLayout reference with the ConstraintLayout instance in the main layout
                        AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) holderbg.getBackground();
                        // Set parameter to our animation
                        // 2500 = 2.5 seconds, 5000 = 5 seconds
                        animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(2000);
                        animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(5000);
                        animationDrawable.start();
                        break;
        }

        mEditor.apply();
    }
```

ERROR refer to below code :-

AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) holderbg.getBackground();

What should I do? What is concept applied?

Your help will be very much appreciated!

Thank you!